# Python: limit on the accuracy of float

Tags: python, rounding, floating-point-precision

The code gives an error because the value of "var" is very close to zero, less than 1e-80. I tried to fix this error using "Import decimal *", but it didn't really work. Is there a way to tell Python to round a number to zero when float number is very close to zero, i.e. < 1e-50? Or any other way to fix this issue?
Thank you
CODE:

```
import math
H=6.6260755e-27
K=1.3807e-16
C=2.9979E+10
T=100.0
x=3.07175e-05

cst=2.0*H*H*(C**3.0)/(K*T*T*(x**6.0))
a=H*C/(K*T*x)
var=cst*math.exp(a)/((math.exp(a)-1.0)**2.0)
print var
```

OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
  var=cst*math.exp(a)/((math.exp(a)-1.0)**2.0)
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

To Kevin:
The code was edited with following lines:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 7
cst=Decimal(2.0*H*H*(C**3.0)/(K*T*T*(x**6.0)))
a=Decimal(H*C/(K*T*x))
```

Comment: _"I tried to fix this error using "Import decimal *", but it didn't really work."_ Why not? Let's see the code where you tried it.

Comment: *"Is there a way to tell Python to round a number to zero when float number is very close to zero, i.e. < 1e-50?"* - `num = 0 if abs(num - 0) < 1e-50 else num`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: program needs to compute "var" first in order to use "if" statement.

Comment: ...yes. It's not clear what you want to know.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe because `import decimal *` is a nonsense statement in Python?

Comment: True, but the code itself does seem to use the syntactically correct `from decimal import *`

Comment: 1)'import decimal *' is not a nonsense statement. https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html
2) I am just trying to fix the error which I am getting when I run the code.

Comment: `import decimal *` isn't a nonsense statement because the `decimal` module doesn't exist (it does), it's a nonsense statement because it's a `SyntaxError`. As noted, the correct syntax is `from decimal import *`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `(math.exp(a)-1.0)**2.0` is too large to hold as an intermediate result.

```
>>> (math.exp(a) - 1.0)**2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

However, for the value of `a` you are using,

```
>>> math.exp(a)/(math.exp(a)-1.0) == 1.0
True
```

so you can essentially cancel that part of the fraction, leaving

```
var = cst/(math.exp(a)-1.0)
```

which evaluates nicely to

```
>>> cst/(math.exp(a)-1.0)
7.932672271698049e-186
```

If you aren't comfortable rewriting the formula to that extent, use the associativity of the operations to avoid the large intermediate value. The resulting product is the same.

```
>>> cst/(math.exp(a)-1.0)*math.exp(a)/(math.exp(a)-1.0)
7.932672271698049e-186
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue but that will work only for this particular problem, not in general. The main issue is the nature of this function:

```
math.exp(a)/(math.exp(a)-1.0)**2.0
```

which decays very rapidly. 
Problem can be easily solved restricting the value of "a" (which won't make any significant change in calculation). i.e.

```
if a>200:
    var=0.0
else:
    var=cst*math.exp(a)/((math.exp(a)-1.0)**2.0)
```